# Devexpress - How to save only the checked records?

Tags: gridview, save, devexpress, records, checked

I have a table called "Details", this table has a column called "invoice", this column is of data type "bit"

The records in this table are displayed in a gridview. I have a button called "btnSaveAll" obviously this button saves all changes made ​​in the records of this table, the problem occurs in certain occasions you need not save all, only some records, for this reason I have that column called "bit".

How I can save only records with column "invoice" in checked?.

I mention the user decide the record that want to save

I am working with dataset and TableAdapters.

Please, helps, THANKS

Button Save ALL

```
private void btnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        DetailsTableAdapter.Adapter.Update(DSDataSet.Details);
}
```

Comment: why do you not change the update query of the adapter??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_ds.UpdateParameters["Name"].DefaultValue = "Burak";

_ds.UpdateParameters["ID"].DefaultValue = 1;

_ds.Update();

i think this is will solve your problem..

Answer (score 1):

You should edit sqldatasource UpdateQuery properties manually.